# Enable / Disable a Google Sheets script based on a sheet named 'settings' where cell A1 = true or false (checked/un-unchecked)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is currently backing up my spreadsheet twice a day. I use a trigger to do this and it works great!
I would like to have the script check the sheet (tab) named 'settings' to see if the checkmark in Cell A1 is checked (true).
If it is true, it will continue to run the backup twice a day.
I am essentially looking to make the cell A1 enable or disable backups.
If cell A1 = True (checked), the backups will continue to run. If the cell A1 is false (unchecked), backups will not run.

Here is my current backup code that works fine. I just want an 'on and off switch':

```js
function Backup() {

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the word "backup" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Backup " + formattedDate;

// gets the destination folder by their ID. REPLACE xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with your folder's ID that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("the_folder_id_goes_here");

// gets the current Google Sheet file
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried to make your script the enable / disable and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function Backup() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("settings");
  if(sh.getRange("A1").getValue() == "FALSE")return;
  var dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Backup " + dts;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("the_folder_id_goes_here");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())
  file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks. I created a new .gs file, assigned a 1 minute trigger to test the code. Unfortunately, the code ran no matter the status of A1 (checked or un-checked).